# Angular module dependency and $route.resolve

Tags: angularjs, module, dependencies

I have an angular module that requires another custom angular module. The consuming module has a `$route.resolve` for one of the routes. If the module dependency is rendered in the page associated with that route, will that dependency module **also** wait for the completion of the resolve? I feel like the dependency module is bootstrapped before the consuming module, and would therefore not wait, but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Angular doesn't distinguish modules after bootstrapping. If a resolver is defined for current route, it will affect this route. If it's not, it won't.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then the functions called from the dependency module's template should not execute until the resolve is completed. Is that right?

Comment: `ng-view` contents (route controller and route template) won't be intialized until route resolvers are resolved, everything else is the consequence.

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick response. I'd be happy to accept your answer if you want to post it as such.

Comment: Sure. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular doesn't distinguish modules after bootstrapping, it doesn't matter which module this dependency belongs to.

If a resolver is defined for current route, it affects this route.

`ng-view` contents (route controller and route template) won't be intialized until route resolvers are resolved. Resolvers won't affect anything outside of `ng-view` directive.